# Конфиг для php приложения

Tags: xml, yaml, json, php, config

Добрый день, возник вопрос в чем лучше хранить конфигурацию приложения (самопис, ООП, MVC)

Склоняюсь к YAML или JSON. На данный момент напсано на php-массивах.

Вот возникла идея переместить в отдельный не php-файл. Т.к. кофиг будет кешироваться на продакшине - в чем хранить с точки производительности не рассматривается. Чисто юзабилити и читабельность.

Comment: кстати, забыл упомянуть, что используется ArrayObject с ARRAY_AS_PROPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле [[@frank](/users/5316/frank)](/users/5316/frank) прав, это кому как больше нравиться.

```
JSON так JSON: $conf = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.js'));
INI так INI: $conf = parse_ini_file('conf.ini');
Array так Array: include 'conf.php';
Objeсt так Object: include 'conf.php'; $conf = new Conf();
```

Comment: вот про ini я что-то забыл, спасибо

Comment: Нда, красивый способ создать неподдерживаемый код - сохранить настройки для php в файле с расширением ".js"...

Answer (score 0):

Это вопрос в стиле 'кому как больше нравится', это как код писать

```
if(){
}

или
if()
{
}
```

По мне так ответ в вопросе.. Конфиг для php приложения -> php массив.

Comment: это вы в php-скриптах привыкли так писать. 
Хотя возможно вы правы, для такого особенного языка - конфиг особый

Кроме как в php не встречал подобной практики конфигов.